# Time difference between first and last row in group in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, group-by

Input

```
Date                  event   
2023-04-11 13:42:16   play   
2023-04-11 14:02:26   play 
2023-04-11 14:36:09   play 
2023-04-11 14:37:46   start
2023-04-11 14:41:34   start
2023-04-11 14:46:27   start
2023-04-11 14:47:03   start
```

Expecting this in pandas dataframe. Group by event order by Date and difference between the first and last time diff.

output

```
date          event   diff
2023-04-11    play    00:53:52 
2023-04-11    start   00:09:17
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a custom [`groupby.agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.aggregate.html):

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])

out = (
 df.groupby([df['Date'].dt.normalize(), 'event'])
   .agg(diff=('Date', lambda g: g.iloc[-1]-g.iloc[0]))
   .reset_index()
)
```

Or reuse the grouper:

```
g = df.groupby([df['Date'].dt.normalize(), 'event'])['Date']

out = g.last().sub(g.first()).reset_index(name='diff')
```

Output:

```
        Date  event            diff
0 2023-04-11   play 0 days 00:53:53
1 2023-04-11  start 0 days 00:09:17
```

##### Non-sorted input

If the data is not initially sorted, use `min`/`max` as aggregation:

```
out = (
 df.groupby([df['Date'].dt.normalize(), 'event'])
   .agg(diff=('Date', lambda g: g.max()-g.min()))
   .reset_index()
)
```

Or:

```
g = df.groupby([df['Date'].dt.normalize(), 'event'])['Date']
out = g.max().sub(g.min()).reset_index(name='diff')
```

This is semantically identical to using `np.ptp`, but for some reason (and unfortunately), much more efficient. Here a timing on 700k rows:

```
# max - min 
99.7 ms ± 2.33 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

# np.ptp
355 ms ± 43.2 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Comment: This assumes that the values are ordered from earliest to latest, right?

Comment: @filpa yes (which seems to be the case here). If not, either first `sort_values` or use `min`/`max` in place of the `iloc`. If the data is already sorted doing so might be more efficient ;)

Comment: @filpa I ran some tests and performance between `min`/`max` and `first`/`last` is actually similar, both are however much faster than `np.ptp` (I'd like to know why, I imagine the detail of its implementation).

Comment: @rose1110 was there any issue with the solution?

Answer (score 3):

Lets do `groupby` and `agg` with [`np.ptp`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ptp.html) i.e. (max - min)

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
df.groupby(['event', df['Date'].dt.date])['Date'].agg(np.ptp).reset_index(name='diff')
```

Result

```
   event        Date            diff
0   play  2023-04-11 0 days 00:53:53
1  start  2023-04-11 0 days 00:09:17
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df1.assign(date=df1.Date.dt.date).groupby('event',as_index=False)\
    .agg(date=("date",'first'),diff=("Date",lambda ss:str(ss.iat[-1]-ss.iat[0])[6:]))
```

Result

```
   event        Date            diff
0   play  2023-04-11 0 days 00:53:53
1  start  2023-04-11 0 days 00:09:17
```